# Ordering output in a table that I am creating

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to apply a 3 way split test to a subset of data, the way that I have been doing this is to create a 'TestTable'

eg

```
Select Group, List, Urn
into tbl_TestSplit
from tbl_AllRecords
where ApplicableToTest = 'Y'
order by List, Urn
```

Then I add some fields:

```
alter table tbl_testsplit
add
[ID][int] identity (1,1) not null,
[Split] [nvarchar] (20) null
```

then I update the split field as follows:

```
update tbl_testsplit set split = {fn MOD(id,3)}
```

However when I check the results of the split it is not splitting the records correctly - usually a few records out on at least one of the lists.  When I investigated this, I noticed that the table it created was not actually in the order I had indicated.

I am sure there is an easier (ie smarter) way to go about this.  Any help gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Rows in a table are not "ordered".

Comment: If you want a guarantee that `IDENTITY` values are assigned in a particular order, you need to create the table first and use `INSERT ... SELECT ... ORDER BY` rather than `SELECT ... INTO ... ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to calculate the row number in the order you want

```
Select Group, List, Urn
     , split = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY List, Urn)) % 3
from   tbl_AllRecords
where  ApplicableToTest = 'Y'
order by List, Urn
```

`%` is the modulo function

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!  This is perfect for what I need, and easy to update if required.  Thank :)